# How to assign value to global array from void?

Tags: c#, arrays

*Hello.I am currently working on a VS form app with pictureboxes gerating random images.Down below i have posted a simplified version of my programme, where error occurs.*

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{      
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;           
    }

    int[] random = new int[16];

    public void LoadImages()
    {  
        List<Image> images = new List<Image>();
        Random rand = new Random();

        images.Add(Properties.strings.firsthero);
        images.Add(Properties.strings.secondhero);
        images.Add(Properties.strings.thirdhero);
        images.Add(Properties.strings.fourthhero);
        images.Add(Properties.strings.fifthhero);
        images.Add(Properties.strings.sixthhero);
        images.Add(Properties.strings.seventhhero);
        images.Add(Properties.strings.eighthero);
        images.Add(Properties.strings.ninethhero);
        images.Add(Properties.strings.tenthhero);
        images.Add(Properties.strings.eleventhhero);
        images.Add(Properties.strings.twelevethhero);
        images.Add(Properties.strings.thirteenthhero);
        images.Add(Properties.strings.fourteenthhero);
        images.Add(Properties.strings.fifteenthhero);

        random[0] = rand.Next(images.Count); 
        pictureBox1.Image = images[random[0]];         
        random[1] = rand.Next(images.Count);           
        pictureBox2.Image = images[random[1]];
        random[2] = rand.Next(images.Count);    
        pictureBox3.Image = images[random[2]];
        random[3] = rand.Next(images.Count);
        pictureBox4.Image = images[random[3]];
        random[4] = rand.Next(images.Count);
        pictureBox5.Image = images[random[4]];
        random[5] = rand.Next(images.Count);
        pictureBox6.Image = images[random[5]];
        random[6] = rand.Next(images.Count);
        pictureBox7.Image = images[random[6]];
        random[7] = rand.Next(images.Count);
        pictureBox8.Image = images[random[7]];
        random[8] = rand.Next(images.Count);
        pictureBox9.Image = images[random[8]];
        random[9] = rand.Next(images.Count);
        pictureBox10.Image = images[random[9]];
        random[10] = rand.Next(images.Count);
        pictureBox11.Image = images[random[10]];
        random[11] = rand.Next(images.Count);
        pictureBox12.Image = images[random[11]];
        random[12] = rand.Next(images.Count);
        pictureBox13.Image = images[random[12]];
        random[13] = rand.Next(images.Count);
        pictureBox14.Image = images[random[13]];
        random[14] = rand.Next(images.Count);
        pictureBox15.Image = images[random[14]];
        random[15] = rand.Next(images.Count);
        pictureBox16.Image = images[random[15]];
    } 

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
       LoadImages();           
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button2.Visible = false;
        button2WasClicked = true; 
        button1Match();
        //the same for other buttons
    }

     public void button1Match()
    {
        if(button1WasClicked == true)
        {              
            if(button2WasClicked == true)
            {                
                if (random[0] == random[1])
                {
                    winsNumber++;
                }
            }
            else if(button3WasClicked == true)
            {                   
                if (random[0] == random[2])
                {
                    winsNumber++;
                }
            }
            else if(button4WasClicked == true)
            {
                if (random[0] == random[3])
                {
                    winsNumber++;
                }
            }
            else if(button5WasClicked == true)
            {
                if (random[0] == random[4])
                {
                    winsNumber++;
                }
            }
            else if(button6WasClicked == true)
            {
                if (random[0] == random[5])
                {
                    winsNumber++;
                }
            }
            else if(button7WasClicked == true)
            {
                if (random[0] == random[6])
                {
                    winsNumber++;
                }
            }
            else if(button8WasClicked == true)
            {
                if (random[0] == random[7])
                {
                    winsNumber++;
                }
            }
            else if(button9WasClicked == true)
            {
                if (random[0] == random[8])
                {
                    winsNumber++;
                }
            }
            else if(button10WasClicked == true)
            {
                if(random[0] == random[9])
                {
                    winsNumber++;
                }
            }
            else if(button11WasClicked == true)
            {
                if (random[0] == random[10])
                {
                    winsNumber++;
                }
            }
            else if(button12WasClicked == true)
            {
                if (random[0] == random[11])
                {
                    winsNumber++;
                }
            }
            else if(button13WasClicked == true)
            {
                if (random[0] == random[12])
                {
                    winsNumber++;
                }
            }
            else if(button14WasClicked == true)
            {
                if (random[0] == random[13])
                {
                    winsNumber++;
                }
            }
            else if(button15WasClicked == true)
            {
                if (random[0] == random[14])
                {
                    winsNumber++;
                }
            }
            else if(button16WasClicked == true)
            {
                if (random[0] == random[15])
                {
                    winsNumber++;
                }
            }

        }

        wins.Text = winsNumber.ToString();
    }
```

So basically I am generatinf random indexes from image list and via them show random images in picture boxes.To find out whether a match between two pictures occurs, I check the indexes of the images in the buttons.
However the problem is that the  random[0] = rand.Next(images.Count); only genrates number in the void, and does not assign random[0] value to the global array. Possible solutins?

Comment: If you look at the debugger, after this call "random[0] = rand.Next(images.Count); ", what is the value you are seeing in random[0]?

Comment: well, I am seeing random value being assigned to random[0] such as 1 or 13 and so on and it works for the other 15 too, but in the LoadImages() only. The thing is when the button1Match method is executed, my random array seems to contain no values, so basically what has happened in LoadImages() stays there.

Comment: I dont see how this can happen. random is an int array that is a class member. Do you close the form sometimes? You wrote it's a simplified version, maybe you can post more code.?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1K3R9azmuxzA5zpXPyiMrmRccTcSrWeTt?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok, so i made a class for my array random but still doesnt function

Comment: I can't access the drive.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XKOGGyhGOqiQf4gsUuzRYgsgS4VcG2uX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: does it work now

Comment: If you first click on "Generate new Images", looks like it's all working. If you dont click on this button in the beginning, there are no values. So call this function in your Form1_Load.